# Word or phrase for the period between starting to learn something and being very fluent at it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When I start to learn something, it often tends to be very confusing and tough. As I learn more, it becomes less complex and I start finding it to be easy.

Is there a phrase, or a word, to define this transitional time period?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a word or a phrase that perfectly defines your requirement. A phrase that you could use is '**[Learning Curve](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/learning-curve)**', which is defined as:

> *the time required to learn certain information, acquire certain skills, etc.*

Comment: Then I may say the learning curve of learning something is deep, right?

Comment: It's usually 'steep' @lerner - 'it's a steep learning curve becoming a chef having only been a washer-upper previously' - in the expression your journey is being likened to a mountain you're climbing, rather than diving in water. 

Comment: You can use adjectives to '_learning curve_' to convey the pace of learning or the time you take. "_The way to the top involves a very steep learning curve._" or "_The easiness of the course ensures a steady learning curve._"

Answer (score -1):

"I'm still a novice." (or beginner)

"I'm still learning."

"I'm in the early stages of learning this."

"I'm slowly getting better at this."

The "early stages" might be what you are looking for. But it doesn't convey how difficult the journey will be.

I'll update if I think of more.